# Рекурсия с шагом N+1 и N+3

Tags: c#, рекурсия

Требуется с помощью рекурсии определить можно ли из массива 1..N, в котором лежать целые неотрицательные числа, получить сумму K, если можно суммировать числа только с индексом i+1 или i+3(начинать с 1 элемента массива).
Я смог написать метод для любых перемещений по массиву:

```
public bool CangetSumOfK(int[] data, int k, int index = 0)
{
    if (k == 0) return true;
    if (k < 0) return false;
    if (index >= data.Length) return false;

    return CangetSumOfK(data, k, index+1) 
    || CangetSumOfK(data, k - data[index], index+1); 
}
```

Как мне его изменить чтобы он работал в моем случае?

Comment: `n+1` - это выход за пределы массива. Вы наверное имели ввиду `i+1`?

Answer (score 0):

```
return 
       CangetSumOfK(data, k, index + 1), 
    || CangetSumOfK(data, k - data[index], index + 1) 
    || CangetSumOfK(data, k, index + 3)
    || CangetSumOfK(data, k - data[index], index + 3);
```

Comment: в этом случае надо будет весь метод запускать для каждого элемента/индекса из массива

Comment: теперь суммируемые элементы могут быть на большом расстоянии др от друга (например, 1 и 101 индексы)